# AWS ElasticBeanStalk environment status is SEVERE despite health returning 200-OK

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have an expressJS code dpeloyed on AWS-ElasticBeanStalk with Application load balancer.

The /var/log/nginx/access.log shows the following

```
{IP ADDRESS} - - [10/Jan/2022:00:52:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 23954 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
```

It is returning 200-OK, but the environment status still shows SEVERE.

Is there something, I am missing.

Following is the entry from /var/log/healthd/daemon.log

```
W, [2022-01-09T22:37:43.641301 #15007]  WARN -- : discarding statistic item after validation error (Invalid timestamp): {:id=>"6", :namespace=>"application", :timestamp=>1641766160, :data=>"{\"duration\":10,\"latency_histogram\":[[0.008,1],[0.009,1]],\"http_counters\":{\"status_200\":2,\"request_count\":2}}"}
```

Does "Invalid TimeStamp has any correlation" with this?

Comment: Per this answer, I have enabled the UDP traffic in the Security Group. Still, it doesn't seem to work.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35859678/140693

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the IAM Role for the EC2 instance. Also, verify the daemon log under \var\log\healthd folder.

If there is a Permission denied error then update the IAM role with the below permission,

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "elasticbeanstalk:PutInstanceStatistics",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```